# In Selenium is not selected select: webdriver + RSpec (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

Please tell me how to use select in Selenium (desirable but not required) in Ruby.
Example:
site:

http://prntscr.com/dvjxjl - list is empty

http://prntscr.com/dvjxss - clicked on the list and it is open (I myself clicked, selenium do not click)

selects code:

```
<select id="list_order">
  <option value="campaign_id">Aktualität</option>
  <option value="status" selected="">status</option>
  <option value="name">name</option>
  <option value="ordered_qty_sum">Verkäufe</option>
</select>
```

my code:

```
element = @driver.find_element xpath: ".//*[@id='list_order']"
select = Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(element)
select.select_by(:value, 'name')
```

so I tried: `select_by(:text, "status")`

I tried to click on the element before creating select

I also tried a variant:

```
element = @driver.find_element xpath: ".//*[@id='list_order']"
all_options = element.find_elements(:tag_name, "option")
all_options.each do |option|
  puts "Value is: " + option.attribute("value")
  option.click if option.attribute("value") == "status"
end
```

Output:

```
Value is: campaign_id
Value is: status
Value is: name
Value is: ordered_qty_sum
```

Those. It sees this value, but do not click on the option.

I can not understand what I'm doing wrong, please help!

Comment: are you sure the 'status' text doesn't have any trailing whitespace?

Comment: @maxple I am absolutely sure of it